# Adding parentheses to python savetxt Panda output file header

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hey I am searching for a way to get the column names in "Parenteses" to my header.
Anyone knows how to do that?

```
 np.savetxt(r'/Users/Desktop/input.txt', df.values, fmt='%d', header="x\ty\tt\id\id2")
```

works fine but i have no "x"  "y"  "t"  "id"  "id2" in the first line of my text file

I tried sth. like:

```
 np.savetxt(r'/Users/Desktop/input.txt', df.values, fmt='%d', header ="("x"+"y")")
```

But it obviously did not work

Any ideas?

Comment: the header is printed just as you give it, with the addition of a comment character.  No formatting.  Just a simple string write.

Comment: Why you just use `df.to_csv`, you can format the columns to whatever you like

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you expect and what is the current output?